# Need code to remove links from posts in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Problem:
I have article with links to its original site and some external links to other sites. I want to remove links base on some condition/input, Like if there is link with google.com, it should be removed. 
I tried fol code but it removes all links.

```
<script>
$('#content a').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

I need code which work on my input. I will use it in WordPress. Thanks for time and effort.

Comment: @Bartolomeu S. Gusella you already helped me before. Will you look at this problem ?

Comment: do you want them removed permanently?

Comment: Yes. it would be better. Thanks

Comment: Hi, any solution please ?

Comment: hey @zain do you also want ***all*** external links gone, no matter where they link to?

Comment: Not all. Only those which i specify. For example if content contains abc.com and xyz.com links and i want to remove abc.com then script should only remove it and other link(s) to remain as they are. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use following Code sample

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#content a').each(function() {
   if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == "http://optimumcreative.com/blog"){
         //After this condition, it will only remove those links who have href value equals to http://optimumcreative.com/blog 
      jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).text());
    }          
  });
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="entry-content">
  This is some text with <a href="http://optimumcreative.com/blog">links</a>. Some more text with <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">links </a>.
  </div>
</div>
```

You will need to put your jQuery code inside document.ready block, so it executes when page is loaded. You can use wp_footer action to load this script as follows

```
  function show_code_footer() {
      echo '<script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              jQuery("#content a").each(function() {
                 jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).text());
              });
         });
      </script>';
 }
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_code_footer' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed answer. Just need to clarify one thing:- will it remove all links ? If yes then can you modify it to remove only **specific links based on domain name** like if content contains link with **abc.com** then it should be removed and all other links to remain in place. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: You can do a if else check inside .each() block then check for URL. Will update the answer shortly

Comment: Thanks. Acutually i am not good with coding. So, your help will be required.

Comment: Can you exactly tell me where to put this code ? I mean functions.php file or at end of each post?

Comment: In functions.php

Comment: I have got error " Only variables can be passed by reference". here is link to screeshot https://ibb.co/m5ZjmW2

Comment: Sorry bro. i will not be able to help you more. You need  to learn basics of programming and wordpress first.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help.